# Spark: split one pairRDD into several

Tags: apache-spark

I have pairRDD t like

```
(1, JOHN SMITH)
(2, JACK J SMITH)
```

And I would like to split them to:

```
(1, JOHN)
(1, SMITH)
(2, JACK)
(2, J)
(2, SMITH)
```

I tried `t.map(t=>(t(0),t(2).split(" ")(0)))`, but this only gives the first token as pairRDD. Don't know how to do the loop to produce everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rdd.flatMap(row => row._2.split(" ").map(name => (row._1, name)))
```

Comment: I suppose you mean Java then.

Comment: Either language, java or scala, deal with pairRDD, not plain RDD

Comment: The above is a pair RDD. See the `row._2` and the `row._1` ? That's picking apart the pair. Did you actually try my code?

Comment: Sorry, you are right! I got a wrong input so first time it didn't work. So pairRDD can use flatMap too.

Comment: Yes of course -- a `pairRDD` is the same thing as an `RDD[Tuple2]`